# I have subclassed unittest.TestCase. Should I still be importing unittest every time I want to use @unittest.skipIf?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have used python unittest quite a bit and there is a decorator method you can use to conditionally skip tests like this:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

@unittest.skipIf(1 == 1, 'Skipped because 1 does indeed equal 1')
def test_upper(self):
    self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')
```

I wanted to add some features to the unittest.TestCase class though, so I subclassed it to start adding my own custom code:

```
import unittest

class CustomTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Just use whatever is in TestCase's init + our stuff
    self.foo = 'foo'  # our stuff
    self.bar = 'bar'

def mymethod(self, param1, param2):  # Some custom method I wanted to make for these custom test cases
    pass
```

To continue using `@unittest.skipIf` I have been sticking `import unittest` at the top of any of my `CustomTestCase` test files, but I wonder if thats the correct way to be doing things. Am I importing more than I need? Or am I worried about nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you've subclassed has little to do with what you're asking. In general, it's fine for subclasses to import or use their superclass: in fact, they *must* import their superclass when they're defined. It's the other way around that's the problem (superclass shouldn't know about its subclasses).

> To continue using @unittest.skipIf I have been sticking import
>   unittest at the top of any of my CustomTestCase test files, but I
>   wonder if thats the correct way to be doing things. Am I importing
>   more than I need?

If you want to use any attribute off of the `unittest` module (including the `skipIf` decorator), then you have to import it into the module in question. It's no more complex than that.

If you're worried about something like header guards, like you need for C/C++ development, don't be. It doesn't work like the `#include` preprocessor directive (i.e. it's not actually including the source of the `unittest` module in your file).

If you're worried about importing `unittest` too many times, don't be. It's extremely common to `import` a module like `unittest` into many different modules of a given project.

> Or am I worried about nothing?

Yes. Just `import unittest` whenever you need it and rid yourself of worry!

HTH.